# Does vector.insert(...) call the constructor or the assignment operator?

Tags: c++, vector, constructor

I have a vector with elements of type `class A`. Class `A` has an explicitly defined copy constructor, but the copy operator has been made private and undefined (it's not meant to be used). If I insert new elements to the vector like below

```
A walker;                      //This calls the default constructor.
std::vector< A > vec;
std::vector< A >::iterator it = vec.begin();
vec.insert( it, walker );      //Shouldn't this call the copy constructor?
```

I get an error complaining that the copy operator is private. But shouldn't vector be using the copy constructor?

Comment: If you are implementing either, you should be implementing both **anyway**....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`vector` is indeed using the copy constructor for the inserted element. However `vector` still needs the assignment operator internally, is within the requeriments for the `vector` type to be assignable. I believe C++11 now only requres move-assignment.

Comment: indeed. It will require _either_ move _or_ 'classic' assignment.

Comment: @sehe Wait, so C++11 provides the introspection needed to determine if one or the other is provided? Is this some ungodly SFINAE hackery or is there a clean solution now?

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: Introspection is not needed, function overloading does it. That said, C++11 provides SFINAE for expressions which should allow to instrospect a lot more stuff than what C++03 does.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: requirements on template parameters are usually not explicitely checked; sometimes, you can use some library template with a type that does not meet all the requirements without being aware that your code may break sometimes (for example, if you don't use the member functions that need this requirement). This was supposed to be improved in C++11 with [concepts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concepts_%28C%2B%2B%29), but this was abandoned. However, even in C++03, it is possible to perform some compile-time introspection to check the presence of some members.

Comment: This can be coupled with static asserts to verify that a given type meet the needed requirements. Several Boost libraries provide features to achieve this.

Comment: @Bruce, Remember that an `insert` doesn't just copy one member. If the vector is growing too long, it needs to find a larger contiguous block of memory to store the longer vector. Then the existing members need to be moved/copied to the new location. Perhaps the copy assignment is used in that case within `insert`?

Answer (score 0):

In msvc or gcc, Vector.insert() internally calls emplace() function.

Firstly if the capacity of vector is equal size of vector, vector is reallocated with twice increased capacity.Object is first inserted/moved (**move constructor is called**) and existing objects are copied at new allocated store(**copy constructor are called**).

if the capacity of vector is greater than size before insertion call, Now if the nsertion is not be done in the end, Object is first inserted/moved (move constructor is called) and existing object are just assigned at the same store(**assigment copy is operator is called**)

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    int i;
    A() = default;
    A(int k) :i(k) { cout << "init"; };
    A(const A&&)
    {
        {cout << "move"; };
    }
    A(const A&)
    {
        {cout << "copy"; };
    }
    A& operator=(const A&)
    {
        std::cout << endl << "assignment" << endl;
        return *this;
    }
   
};




int main()
{
    // vector<int> vi(5);  // just to show that std::vector always default initializes values & hence int will be 0 here

  // A a(2);
   // A a= 2;

    vector<A> va(4); // ---> calls default
    cout << "------" << va.capacity() << "-";
  

  va.emplace_back(2); 
 

  
    cout << "------"<<va.capacity()<<"-"<<va.size()<<"--";
    va.push_back(2);
    
    va.insert(va.begin(), 4);

    return 0;
}
```

------2-
init move copy copy
------4-3--
initmove
assignment

assignment
move
assignment